# conditional filter SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My situation is

1. I have a parameter, this is a list, allowing multi values. That mean the first record in the list is 'Select All'
2. When user select All I need to include in my report all records that match with the list plus those that are blank. (My dataset is returning these)
3. When user select only 1 or a few I want to include only these records. No those that are blank

My problem: 
I have a filter in my dataset that evaluate a parameter in a list, but I need to add a conditional filter to include a blank records when the selection will be "Select All" 
I tried to use expression but this doesn't work

Filter expression
`Fields!NAME.Value in = Parameters!List.Value`  !!!!!!!!!!!!   Work Fine

But I need to change it like as

```
If Parameters!List.Value  =  'Select All' Then
   Fields!NAME.Value in = Parameters!List.Value  or Fields!NAME.Value = " "
Else
   Fields!NAME.Value in = Parameters!List.Value
End
```

Can you give an advice who can I resolve it please !!!

I'm working in SSRS R2

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative for this.

Add one more item to the paramater dataset values say "Not Available" as Label and value with the null. then there will be no change in the stored procedure and you can retrieve the data.
If the user select the specific item then he will get those values only. If he selects all then he will get the data for the null also with the all the others.

Hope this will help

Comment: I don't think that it's a solution, my dataset is working fine, returning the null records as well, I'm complicate to filter/include these in my SSRS depending if user "Select ALL" OR no.

Comment: I want to know how can I write in SSRS 2008 something like in a filter                                                             If Parameters!List.Value  =  'Select All' Then
   Fields!NAME.Value in = Parameters!List.Value  OR Fields!NAME.Value = " "
Else
   Fields!NAME.Value in = Parameters!List.Value
End

Comment: With the Select All you can not check the conditions that's why I am saying to have a value added to the parameter. In SP you might be checking like "Value Is NULL OR Value IN (@ParamValueList)". That's why it is returning the null values. I used this procedure to filter the data.

Comment: you mean that I've to made the filter in a SP instead of SSRS?

Comment: Yes, Suppose you have the parameters with the Labkes as XXX,YYY,ZZZ and 1,2,3 as the values for that then Add the Not Available. Now the parameters contain labels as XXX,YYY,ZZZ,NotAvailable with the values as 1,2,3,null. Use the union in the Parameter dataset to achieve this from which you are getting the values. In the SP you will check the Value IN (@ParamValueList). If he selects all then it will include the "Not Available" so the value null also will be in the list. The performance wise the filtering in the SP will be faster than in the SSRS.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

Expression: =IIF(Parameters!pLocation.Value <> " All Locations", Fields!LOCATION.Value, FALSE)
Operator: = 
Value: =IIF(Parameters!pLocation.Value <> " All Locations", Parameters!pLocation.Value, FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Filter on your Dataset, try this:

```
Expression: [NAME]
Operator: IN
Value (fx): =Split(Replace(Join(Parameters!List.Value, ","), "Select All", " "), ",")
```

Try to work along this path. Basically you can reconstruct the multi value items into a string with Join(), and deconstruct it again into array by using Split(); where in between, you can manipulate them, for modifying (e.g. converting "Select All" into " "), adding (imitating "OR"), or removing extra items.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the logic in just one location if you do it this way.
You filter on the parameter, unless it's all values then the filter always matches.
Just a little cleaner.

Expression: =IIF(Parameters!pLocation.Value <> " All Locations", Fields!LOCATION.Value, " All Locations")

Operator: =

Value: =Parameters!pLocation.Value